# Web Scraping using Python sometimes fetch result sometimes results in HTTP 429

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape reddit pages for the videos. I am using python and beautiful soup to do the job.The following code sometimes return the result and sometimes not when I rerun the code.I'm not sure where i'm going wrong.  Can someone help? I'm a newbie to python so please bear with me.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/FortNiteBR/comments/afjbbp/just_trying_to_revive_my_buddy_and_then_he_got/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

source_tags = soup.find_all('source')

print(source_tags)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do `print (page)` after your `page = requests.get('https:/.........')`, you'll see you get a successful `<Response [200]>`

But if you run it quickly again, you'll get the `<Response [429]>`

"The HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response status code indicates the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting")." Source [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)

Additonally, if you look at the html source, you'd see:

```
<h1>whoa there, pardner!</h1>
<p>we're sorry, but you appear to be a bot and we've seen too many requests
from you lately. we enforce a hard speed limit on requests that appear to come
from bots to prevent abuse.</p>
<p>if you are not a bot but are spoofing one via your browser's user agent
string: please change your user agent string to avoid seeing this message
again.</p>
<p>please wait 6 second(s) and try again.</p>
<p>as a reminder to developers, we recommend that clients make no
    more than <a href="http://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API">one
    request every two seconds</a> to avoid seeing this message.</p>
```

To add headers and avoid the 429 add in:

```
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36"}

page = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/FortNiteBR/comments/afjbbp/just_trying_to_revive_my_buddy_and_then_he_got/', headers=headers)
```

**Full code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36"}

page = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/FortNiteBR/comments/afjbbp/just_trying_to_revive_my_buddy_and_then_he_got/', headers=headers)
print (page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

source_tags = soup.find_all('source')

print(source_tags)
```

**Output:**

```
<Response [200]>
[<source src="https://v.redd.it/et9so1j0z6a21/HLSPlaylist.m3u8" type="application/vnd.apple.mpegURL"/>]
```

and have had no issues rerunning multiple times after waiting a second or 2

Comment: How much time should i wait to send another request?

Comment: It says 6 seconds.

Comment: or you could ad a headers (see edit above). But then it still says you should wait atleast 2 seconds.

Comment: I tried waiting for 6 secs but it still does not work

Comment: what response are you getting? is it 429 or 504? I'd also include those headers if I were you, that should alleviate the 429

Comment: It seems to work now. Appreciate the help and quick responses

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below code and it is working for me at every request, Added timeout of 30 sec.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/FortNiteBR/comments/afjbbp/just_trying_to_revive_my_buddy_and_then_he_got/', timeout=30)
if page.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    source_tags = soup.find_all('source')
    print(source_tags)
else:
    print(page.status_code, page)
```

Comment: I still getting 429 response. Not sure what i'm doing wrong. i'm a newbie so please bear with me

Comment: @JON instead of timeout better to add a delay of 30s or so when the status_code is 429.